# How does Jenks optimisation method assist in ESRI mapping?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, optimization

Why would someone use the [Jenks optimisation method in ESRI mapping?](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/26442)

What would be easily located or discovered with this analysis?

Comment: Is this a question from homework or schoolwork?

Comment: @GeoKevin No, I'm independently studying [income distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/67571/4842) and came across this.  Wikipedia says it's used in GIS, so I hope that by understanding the analysis in a physical sense I can apply it to properties in economics.

Comment: For what it's worth, this thought exercise will help me create an alternate version of [Bitcoin](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) with the [GNI coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Homework questions are not forbidden, but it is preferred that they're noted as such.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting application.

Comment: I'm looking for thought leaders in the project.  The goal is to create a virtual currency that encourages a gradient-style blending of one income tier to another, but doesn't force it.  The 1% and the 99% would hopefully get along better in this "new world" I'm working on.  If you're interested, hit me up on myname at gmail or we can talk in chat.

Answer (score 5):

I was wondering the same thing the other day and found an interesting article experimentally comparing different classification methods. The experiment is about showing the same data with 7 different classification methods, asking questions about the data, and seeing how accurate the answers are for each classification. The particular experiment suggests that Quantile may be the best of 7 methods tested for "general map-reading tasks".

Cynthia A. Brewer and Linda Pickle 
 "Evaluation of methods for classifying epidemiological data on choropleth maps in series" 
 Annals of the Association of American Geographers 92 4, pp.662–681 (2002)  http://scripts.cac.psu.edu/users/c/a/cab38/Brewer_Annals.pdf

As I am not answering your question directly, I wanted to post this as a comment but I have less than 50 reputaion so I could not.

Comment: In Natural Breaks, I think it is sometimes more informative if each class shows the minimum and maximum attribute values in that class as boundary values instead of forcing the boundary values of adjoining classes to coincide (and perhaps "a - b no features" between classes in the legend).

Answer (score 3):

Jenks optimazation method is a way to classify your data into groups, so that the variance within each group is as small as possible, while the variance between the groups is high as possible. I would not call it an analysis method per se. Its used for creating choropleth-maps

Comment: It's frequently used for choropleth mapping, but not exclusively. It can be used for any thematic mapping when a range of data values should be divided into natural breaks, regardless of whether the data is represented as points, lines, or polygons (only poly's would be used for choropleth maps).

Comment: Jenks' method is the one-dimensional version of [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). As such it is a method of analyzing data and is used much more widely than merely mapping data.

Answer (score 0):

Quantify areal variables, classify chloropeth mapping on natural breaks. Discover outliers, Fit bell curves to natural classifications with low variance within classes.

Comment: Practically by definition, if Jenks' method discovers real breaks in the data, then "bell curves" are poor descriptions indeed and should not be fit at all.

Comment: Unless the data is describing a bell curve with outliers, then the breaks would be algorithmic in nature, naturally ; ) Then you would be creating a natural classification that identifies outliers.

Comment: There are better ways to identify outliers. A good overview is presented in Madansky, *Prescriptions for Working Statisticians,* and for more information there is all the material in Barnett & Lewis, *Outliers in Statistical Data.*

Comment: Thank you @whuber. There are in fact, much better ways to identify outliers! When using Jenks keep in mind that it finds breaks in the distribution and is dependent on the number of breaks defined. If you have a skewed (long tailed) distribution and define too many breaks you may get meaningless divisions along the tail. If you have an outlier effect these bins may not represent any actual data data. The R package calssInt has a jenks.test function that will provide a goodness of fit on number of clusters. You can iterate and find the best supported k. There is also a Kmeans option.